# Saltstack Windows software distribution problems

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to create a win repo within my isolated environment.

At the /etc/salt/master I added the lines:

```
winrepo_dir_ng: repo
winrepo_insecure_auth: True
winrepo_cachefile: winrepo.p
```

On the minion configuration file (a windows minion):

```
winrepo: salt-master://win/repo
winrepo_cachefile: 'c:/salt/repo/cache'
```

Of course after that I used the following commands:

```
salt-run winrepo.genrepo
```

returns the sls content

```
salt '*' pkg.refresh_db
```

returns empty line (should be 'true').

When I try `"salt '*' pkg.install notepad"` it returns `"unable to locate package notepad".`

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

comment out all those lines you've configured in your master and minion configs. The defaults should all work fine.